# How to put an image with css dynamically with wagtail

Tags: css, django, image, wagtail

I'm using the django cms wagtail, but it has an image that needs to be dynamically placed and needs to be css

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url({% static 'img/home-bg.jpg' %})">
```

Comment: Perhaps the second option under http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.4/topics/images.html#more-control-over-the-img-tag (`{% image page.photo width-400 as tmp_photo %}`) is what you're looking for?

Comment: Less optimally you can also add it in your css file : **background-image: url('/static/img/home-bg.jpg');**

Comment: I do this by adding a <style> tag in the template/render.  This is how my CMS works to position parallax image.  I also have added <script> tags in the render with JSON that has information for the image placement.